# htaccess help moving Expression Engine site to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, expressionengine

I currently have an Expression Engine blog which I am going to move over to Wordpress, the current url structure is /blog/comments/page-title

I have imported the posts into Wordpress and I'm going to keep the same page title's for the pretty urls but just want the address to be /page-title

the Wordpress htaccess file is as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

can anybody tell me how I do this additional redirect in this block? Also will this totally ensure that search engine indexing won't be affected as it has been running for 4 years and I have over 1700 blog posts currently indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this before your WordPress rules in your .htaccess file:

`RedirectMatch ^/blog/comments/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301]`

This will redirect `http://yourdomain.com/blog/comments/my-post` to `http://yourdomain.com/my-post`, and tell search engines that the redirect is permanent.

One note: WordPress discourages the use of `/%postname%/` as a permalink structure as it adds many more queries to determine the content to load. From http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks:

> Starting Permalinks with %postname% is strongly not recommended for performance reasons.

So I'd suggest instead using something like `/blog/%postname%` instead, in which case your rule would look like:

`RedirectMatch ^/blog/comments/(.+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301]`

Comment: Wow that's perfect thank you very much! Also thanks for the performance tip too.

Comment: I know this should work and I've read many times that this is the correct way to do this but I can't get it to work, is it definitely (.+) not (.*)? I tried both, the second gave me an internal server error. I have wordpress in a subdirectory /wordpress and an htaccess file in each.

Comment: Ok I tried this: RedirectMatch ^/blog/comments/(.+)$ /wordpress/blog/$1 [R=301] for the htaccess file in the root but then I get an internal server error

Comment: ok I'll try now, my wordpress installation is in a subdirectory should the htaccess file in that dir have this in it too? also should it be RedirectMatch ^/blog/comments/(.+)$ /wordpress/blog/$1 or just RedirectMatch ^/blog/comments/(.+)$ /blog/$1 thanks for your help :)

Comment: aha! got it, a space managed to find its way into my wordpress htaccess rules as you can see above RewriteRule . /index.php [L] thank you so much for your help D-Rock!